# Permission denied when calling a script, although I'm the user who's permitted to call it

Tags: shell-script, permissions

I've added "x" to the sh scripts in a directory:

```
$ whoami
alex

$ sudo chmod og+x ./scripts/*.sh
```

And so I have

```
$ ls -al ./scripts/
total 24
drwxr-xr-x  2 alex alex 4096 Jan 25 10:33 .
drwxr-xr-x 12 alex alex 4096 Jan 25 10:43 ..
-rw-r-xr-x  1 alex alex  228 Nov 24 09:37 aabbcc.sh
-rw-r-xr-x  1 alex alex 4455 Nov 24 16:29 deploy.sh
```

But when I do this

```
$ ./scripts/deploy.sh
```

I'll get this:

```
bash: ./scripts/deploy.sh: Permission denied
```

Why hasn't it worked?

Comment: You set the execute permission for your group and for "others", but did not grant it for your user itself. I guess "withdrawing/withholding" the execute permission for a user overrides it if the user is also in a group that has execute permission ...

Comment: Why did you use `sudo`?

Answer (score 6):

You only gave executable permission to the "group" and "others" but you didn't add it for the file's owner, you. So everyone can execute this, *except* you. So just add execution right for the owner as well and you're all set:

```
chmod u+x ./scripts/*.sh
```

Do NOT use `sudo` when it isn't needed!

Comment: I tried to find documentation on whether "withdrawing" the execute permission for a user overrides that the user may be "indirectly" permitted to execute via the group; do you have any reference where this is explicitly stated?

Comment: @AdminBee no, and it came as a surprise to me too. I just tested and confirmed that I can't execute a file with `terdon:terdon` ownership and execution allowed for group and other. Despite being a member of the terdon group. I am assuming the test is hierarchical so since it's owned by me and I don't have user executable permissions, it doesn't even check the others. I am just guessing though.

Comment: I also tested it and concur; it just would have been nice to find it documented somewhere ... :)

Comment: I don't know of any references. But the algorithm (for opening/executing a file) first looks are you the owner, are you in the group, else you are other. Then it looks at the `rwx` mode bits, but only the relevant ones. (it will **not** look at the other ⅔ of the `rwx` bits.

Comment: the group is "alex" and "whoami" is alex, and also, I've just checked, my user "alex" is in the group "alex" too. Therefore, there's an intersection in any case, but it didn't work

Comment: @DoctorDoom338 yes, we know. What we're saying is that if you are the owner, then it's the owner permissions that are relevant, none of the others will be checked.

Comment: And I also should USE sudo when it isn't needed, right?

Comment: @DoctorDoom338 sorry? No, you should not use `sudo` unless you know it is needed since using it is a) a serious risk since you can make a mistake and break your machine and ii) can cause headaches when doing things in your $HOME since it can change the ownership of files to root. So generally, avoid using it unless you need to run something as root.

Comment: Ok, we'll use sudo  when it isn't needed. We always use sudo and will continue to use it